# MVC4 URL Routing : Optional parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, url-routing

In my `MVC4` application, I want to show the data to users according to the client. I want to achieve this using `URL routing`.
e.g.
1. http://mysite.com/abc/account/login
2. http://mysite.com/xyz/account/login

Here, 'abc' and 'xyz' are referred as clientcode. If user enters first url, then the application will connect to database for client 'abc'. If user enters second url, then it will connect to database for client 'xyz'.

I want to achieve the above functionality. So how should i make use of routing.

I have used following code in RouteConfig -

```
routes.MapRoute(
           name: "Default",
           url: "{clientcode}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
           defaults: new { clientcode = UrlParameter.Optional, controller = "Account", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
       );
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens when you hit those URLs?

Comment: Sorry for incomplete description.
if user enter url without client code e.g. http://mysite.com/account/login , then application should connect to default database.
other wise it should connect to client-specific database. I can get the database connectionstring from clientcode, for that i have to read clientcode from the url (RouteData).
The url I mentioned above are dummy url.

Answer (score 0):

You can only make the last parameter optional in ASP.NET MVC. Instead of changing the default route, create a new route for this specific URL. Make sure you add this one before the default route.

```
routes.MapRoute(
           name: "Login",
           url: "{clientcode}/account/login",
           defaults: new { clientcode = UrlParameter.Optional, controller = "Account", action = "Login" }
       );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by reading `ControllerContext.RouteData`. The `RouteData` object contains `Values` `RouteValueDictionary` that you can read and query for `clientcode`. For example:

```
var clientCode = ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["clientcode"];

if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(clientCode))
{
    // Set to a default value
    clientCode = "default_value";
}

// Do something with clientCode

return ViewResult(); // or RedirectToAction("ActionName")
```

That's about it.